# Can I run an infinite loop in my java program to check if a third party have done somechanges in the database

Tags: java, mysql, infinite-loop, multiple-users

I am designing a program in java and using mysql as DB. The program allows multiple users to connect to the DB.

An important part of the program is instantly updating the users that another one has made a change in a specific table that will have the user do an action and hence the changes will be show on his end.

I thought of listening on a socket but I couldn't resolve the concept of multiple users and how the sender will notify a specific user only not the entire group

**this is similar to text message**

So what I am trying to do is run a while loop that runs every 10 seconds to enhance the performance a little bit and will check the table against the username I am using to log in 
this will get me what I wan but I know it is not efficient

Any Ideas ???

Comment: If you're doing the writing, why would you need to check the database to see if something was changed?

Comment: @shmosel I am not the one doing the writing

Comment: multiple users writing to the database and I want to notify them if one has made a change

Comment: They're writing directly to the database? That's highly unusual. They should be go through a web app.

Comment: this is a program to manage a clinic with 3 doctors. they both write to the same DB on the same server. what I am trying to do is to get a certain doctor notified if the reception adds a visit for him. Also send text message from one user to the other. the data of the text is stored in a table with the recipient user. however the user will not be notified until he makes an action. I am trying to avoid that by having a loop continuously check for update

Comment: You should never have a client application communicating directly with a database server. You need to create a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "version control" pattern in the database table. Add a numeric column that is incremented each time the table is updated, such as:

```
alter table users add version_number bigint:
```

Then, each time the row is updated, you should increment this value as well:

```
update users
  set my_value = ...,
    version_number = version_number + 1 -- include this change
  where id = 1234
```

This way, each client will remember the last version_number they *saw*. I they find a different version number, then a change has happened so an action should be taken.